# Element-wise division between two images using emgu

Tags: c#, emgucv

I want to perform an element-wise division between two images. I am using emgucv and tried the following but it doesn't perform element-wise division.

```
Image<Gray, double> A = new Image<Gray, double>(634, 474);
Image<Gray, double> B = new Image<Gray, double>(634, 474);
Image<Gray, double> C = new Image<Gray, double>(634, 474);
CvInvoke.cvDiv(A.Ptr, B.Ptr, C.Ptr, 1);
```

How can I perform an element-wise division operation like the following:

```
C[i,j]=A[i,j]/B[i,j];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `A[i,j]/B[i,j] = A[i,j] * (1/B[i,j]) = A[i,j] * B[i,j]^(-1)`, you should be able to do it this way:

```
C = A.Mul(B.Pow(-1));
```

I haven't tested it though.